# How do I insert the results from multiple dropdown menus, which have multiple answers from a form into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, drop-down-menu

I am creating a massive, relational database in MySQL and using PHP to process a form.  The MySQL table has the following fields:

- Server_Name
- Location_id
- Location_Contact
- app_contact_O
- app_contact_Contact
- OS_id
- Database_id
- Vendor_id
- last_update
- updated_by

For every Server Name, there can be multiple Location Contacts, app_contact_O's, app_contact_Contacts, and Database_id's.

The multiple fields are inputted through a dropdown menu where you can select the multiple choices.

How do I get the multiple fields into the database.  I've tried a number of different solutions and have not found anything that works.

I can get the results into MySQL from a single drop-down menu using a foreach() loop, but I need help from the multiples.

My code for this page is like 438 lines long...I don't think it would be useful to the community to post.

==========================
Okay let me clarify using a shortened version of the form:

I have the following form:

```
    <form action="" method="post">
    Server Name: <input type="text" name="Server_Name" size="40" /><br />

    Location: <select name="servLocation">
    <option value="none" selected="selected">Select Location</option>
    <?php
    $getLocation=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM locationTable ORDER BY Location");
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($getLocation)){
    extract($r);
    echo "<option value='" . $Location_id . "'>" . $Location . ": " . $City . ", " . $Country . ", " . $GSL_id . "</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <br />

    Location Contact: 
    <select name="servLocCon[]" multiple='multiple' size="3">
    <option value="none" selected="selected">Select Contact</option>
    <?php
    $getContacts=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hpatt.contacts ORDER BY Last_Name");
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($getContacts)){
    extract($r);
    echo "<option value='" . $Contact_id . "'>" . $Last_Name . ", " . $First_Name . "</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select><br />

    Application Contact:
    <select name="servAppCon[]" multiple='multiple' size="3">
    <option value="none" selected="selected">Select Contact</option>
    <?php
    $getContactsB=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hpatt.contacts ORDER BY Last_Name");
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($getContactsB)){
    extract($r);
    echo "<option value='" . $Contact_id . "'>" . $Last_Name . ", " . $First_Name . "</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Okay, So what I want to do is have the user to have the option to select multiple location contacts and application contacts for 1 server.  Which is accomplished using the size and multiple attributes.  Then I want a separate record to be inserted into the MySQL table to read like the following:

Record 1:
ServerA, Wendel Holmes, John Smith

Record 2:
ServerA, Wendy Martin, John Smith

Record 3:
ServerA, Wendel Holmes, Juanita Gomez

Record 4:
ServerA, Wendy Martin, John Smith

So that every possibility is handled and then can be extracted.  I can do this manually, by creating records individually, but PHP should be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite follow you, but say I had a table:

```
SID  Server Name
1    S1
2    S2
3    S3
```

I would make an xref table, such as:

```
SID   Prop1   Prop2 ...  PropX
1      1        2          11
1      2        5          12
2      1        1          33
3      4        2          4
```

In this case the SID is used multiple times in the xref table.

Each prop is actually an ID into some other table.

Then I make a multi-column key on the xref table to prevent duplicate rows.

You can get all the POST/GET results of a multi select in a similar fashion as to a single select.

For example, using your `serverLocCon[]`:

```
$sLocCon = $_POST['servLocCon'];

foreach ($sLocCon as $item) 
...
```

Comment: In the actual file, there are 4 dropdown menus capable of having multiple values.  I want to insert them into 1 table, having 1 record for every unique value for the Location contact, Application Owner, Application Contact, and Database, because many of these servers have multiples contacts and multiple databases for each server.  I have tried using foreach but it only inserts 1 record.  If I have 4 app contacts, 2 location contacts, 5 application owners, and 2 databases, I need it to create 11 records, 1 for every unique possibility.

Answer (score 0):

for example for **location** field who have multiple value, you can create a table with the same name **(location: id, name)** and other table named **location_server(id_location,id_server)**